# Can Vite be configured to run a custom middleware function using the server proxy setting in vite.config.js?

Tags: javascript, python, refactoring, vite, aiohttp

So I have a legacy project that is built on `Python` and using `aiohttp` server to serve static HTML,CSS and JS files. The entire front end is one giant `jQuery` file that's something like 10,000 lines long.

I've been asked to refactor the entire thing over to `React` and I want to use Vite (if I can) for development.

So far it's working. I'm using Vite to load the HTML and JS and then proxying all api calls to the Python backend. But one issue I still have is that it supports multiple languages. For that we are using `Polyglot.js` library and I need to have it run that library on the HTML when Vite reloads the page.

I was thinking I could somehow process the HTML file and do the language translations by running my own little middlware inside of the server proxy settings as describe by `vite.config.js`.

So my idea is something like this.

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
    
      '/': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        changeOrigin: true,
        configure: (proxy, options) => {


             // call some custom JavaScript here
             // 1) Grab HTML
             // 2) Run the page through Polyglot library
             // 3) Spit page out to the browser  
        },
      },

    },
  },
})
```

Would this be possible and if not is there a plugin for something like this?

Thanks so much in advance